# Entity framework and Stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_Some_Data
    @Sreachstr nvarchar(200)
AS
 BEGIN
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Document].DocNo DESC) AS Row,*
    FROM Document WHERE DocNo=@Sreachstr 
 END
```

when I execute it with `@Sreachstr='153'`, it returns 15 records.

I use Entity Framework to get the data returned by the stored procedure:

```
public static List<DocumentInfo_Full_Data> SelectByDocNo(string SearchStr)
{
    using (LibEntities_new db = new LibEntities_new())
    {
        return SelectByDocNo(db, SearchStr);
    }
}

private static List<DocumentInfo_Full_Data> SelectByDocNo(LibEntities_new db, String SearchStr)
{
    return db.SelectByDocNo(SearchStr).ToList();
}

public ObjectResult<DocumentInfo_Full_Data> SelectByDocNo(global::System.String searchStr)
{
    ObjectParameter searchStrParameter;
    if (searchStr != null)
    {
        searchStrParameter = new ObjectParameter("SearchStr", searchStr);
    }
    else
    {
        searchStrParameter = new ObjectParameter("SearchStr", typeof(global::System.String));
    }

    return base.ExecuteFunction<DocumentInfo_Full_Data>("SelectByDocNo", searchStrParameter);
}
```

When I call this method with parameter `SearchStr="15"` , I see one record that 15 times is repeated instead of 15 different records.

Comment: What is the **primary key** defined on your `Document` table in the database? Which field is defined as the **key** in your EF entity?

Comment: A field by name recno is primary in Document Table

Comment: And is this also your **key** in the Entity Framework entity class?

Comment: The fact you are getting 15 results exactly suggests the code displaying the results might have a bug. Does the SQL work run just against the DB directly? Does SqlProfiler show the expected SQL being run? This would eliminate the SQL itself as the source of the problem, and eliminate the wrong SQL being executed by EF as the problem.

Comment: in sql server management studio sp works properly

Comment: ...and with SQL profiler you see the same SQL being executed by EF? By the way, I presume there is a typo in your question, as you write 153 as the param value initially, and 15 when you mention it towards the end.

Comment: "153" is param value and 15 is number of records that returns

Comment: I've had this situation once when selecting from a view - since that view didn't have a primary key, EF would use all **non-nullable** columns from the view as the key; but since those columns all had the same value for all 4 rows being returned, EF returned only the first row - but 4 times. Therefore my question: **is the `RecNo` field REALLY the KEY in your EF entity?** (in the `DocumentInfo_Full_Data` class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen to me once when I was selecting rows from a view in EF.

Since the view itself doesn't have a primary key, EF wasn't able to determine the key - instead, EF created a "guessed" key based on all non-nullable columns from the view.

My view returned four rows of data, e.g.

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4 
  1      2     'ABC'   42
  1      2     'DEF'   57 
  1      2     'GHI'   4711 
  1      2     'JKL'   404
```

--> my query worked **just fine** in SQL Server Management Studio.

The "key" that EF had guessed was based on `(Col1, Col2)`.

Now when I retrieved the rows using EF, this happen:

- the first row got selected - EF saw it didn't have any data yet, so it stored that row in its result set
- the next row was selected - EF determined that the **key** was the same ( `(1,2)` again) so it assumed this was the same row again; same key -> same row, so that same entity got stored a second, third and fourth time

So in the end, what I got back from EF was

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4 
  1      2     'ABC'   42
  1      2     'ABC'   42
  1      2     'ABC'   42
  1      2     'ABC'   42
```

because the **key** that determines uniqueness of an entity in EF was the same for each of the four columns from the database.

So this might be happening in your case, too - especially if your created a new complex type for your data returned from the stored procedure - and if your **key** on the EF entity (`DocumentInfo_Full_Data`) is not properly set to an actual, really identifying column (or set of columns) from the database. Check it out!

Comment: thanks for your post. I set Entity Key and so Now every things are OK